# How to know if im pushing a button in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.1

I am trying to get this button

> ```
> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg" name='submit'>
>     Retrieve
> </button>
> ```

in my Middleware and I want to verify if I'm pushing this button, this is my middleware:

> ```
> public function handle($request, Closure $next){
>       $var = isset($_POST[$request->submit]);$other = ((bool) $var);
>       if (redirect('retrieve_money')) {
>           return redirect()->guest(route('home'));
>       } else if ($other) {
>           return redirect()->guest(route('retrieve_money.index'));
>       }
> }
> ```

I don't know how to verify how to know if someone is pushing this button.

Comment: set `name` of Submit button.

Comment: You can give the submit button a name, then check if it was set in the post variable.

Comment: name='submit' that's the name

Comment: Then check an input called 'submit'. If it is there, the user submitted the form by clicking the button. If it is not there, the form was submitted by other way.

Comment: The input is taking all the info that i send, but i want to know if im pushing the button with the name submit! Thanks for the answers

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think <button> actually creates a POST value when clicked. Have you tried changing it to <input type="submit"> ?

Answer (score 0):

I am considering your form is `GET`.

Just have this inside your `VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
$submit = $request->submit;
        if (isset($submit)) {
            echo $submit;
        }
```

And then your button should be changed like

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg" >`

Then if you click the submit then you should see the submit's value in the top of the page.

**Tip :**

You shall see the output directly by page's source by

`view-source:http://localhost/yourproject/?submit=1221`

Comment: This is the route that the submit send me  http://localhost:8000/retrieve_money and this form is POST, but i need to block if someone write http://localhost:8000/retrieve_money before click the submit

Comment: You mean, it should be accessed only via submit event and not from direct url ?